# Gatsby preview server in a serverless/stateless environment

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, gatsby

Gatsby has [documentation on how to setup a preview server here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/running-a-gatsby-preview-server/)

Problem is it requires a server running 24/7 listening to requests, I would like to achieve the same result but in a serverless setup (AWS Lambda to be more specific) since we would need a preview very rarely.

The context here is using Gatsby with Wordpress as a headless data backend, and I want to implement a custom preview link in Wordpress for previewing posts before publishing them.

So far, there are two main setbacks :

1. Size, currently the size of node_modules for a Gatsby starter with Wordpress is 570mb
2. Speed, stateless means every preview request would be running `gatsby develop` again

I honestly don't know a solution for size here, not sure how to strip down packages.

As for speed, maybe there's a low level Gatsby API function to directly render a page to HTML? For example, a Node.js Lambda code could look like this (buildPageHTML is a hypothetical function I'm trying to find)

```js
import buildPageHTML from "gatsby"

exports.handler = async function(event) {
  const postID = event.queryStringParameters.postID
  return buildPageHTML(`/preview_post_by_id/${postID}`)
}
```

Any ideas on how to go on about this?

Comment: I’m not sure why you can’t use gatsby build?

Comment: @DallasBaker that's intended for builds, not for previewing content that is rapidly changing

Comment: Can you not use reactRenderToString or renderToStaticMarkup? [React DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)

Answer (score 1):

### Running Gatsby in an AWS Lambda

Try this lamba (from [this](https://www.jameshill.dev/articles/running-gatsby-within-aws-lambda/) beautiful tutorial) :

```
import { Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { link } from 'linkfs';
import mock from 'mock-require';
import fs from 'fs';
import { tmpdir } from 'os';
import { runtimeRequire } from '@/utility/runtimeRequire.utility';
import { deployFiles } from '@/utility/deployFiles.utility';

/* -----------------------------------
 *
 * Variables
 *
 * -------------------------------- */

const tmpDir = tmpdir();

/* -----------------------------------
 *
 * Gatsby
 *
 * -------------------------------- */

function invokeGatsby(context: Context) {
  const gatsby = runtimeRequire('gatsby/dist/commands/build');

  gatsby({
    directory: __dirname,
    verbose: false,
    browserslist: ['>0.25%', 'not dead'],
    sitePackageJson: runtimeRequire('./package.json'),
  })
    .then(deployFiles)
    .then(context.succeed)
    .catch(context.fail);
}

/* -----------------------------------
 *
 * Output
 *
 * -------------------------------- */

function rewriteFs() {
  const linkedFs = link(fs, [
    [`${__dirname}/.cache`, `${tmpDir}/.cache`],
    [`${__dirname}/public`, `${tmpDir}/public`],
  ]);

  linkedFs.ReadStream = fs.ReadStream;
  linkedFs.WriteStream = fs.WriteStream;

  mock('fs', linkedFs);
}

/* -----------------------------------
 *
 * Handler
 *
 * -------------------------------- */

exports.handler = (event: any, context: Context) => {
  rewriteFs();
  invokeGatsby(context);
};
```

find the source [here](https://github.com/jhukdev/gatsby-lambda/blob/master/src/lambda.ts)

Comment: where is `gatsby` defined in your code? the tutorial you linked is great but it builds all pages, I only want to build a single page for preview and return its HTML

Comment: I updated my answer, and if you only want to build a single page for preview you can do it that way ; with this lambda you can build a page `preview_post_by_id` and gather postId in this page to create your preview. lambda will be executed just to rebuild any update